# Transparent video in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, alpha

I have several .mov videos with an alpha channel that I want to include in my Unity project.
I use Unity 2018.4LTS plus for this project (it breaks if I upgrade to 2019).
in the unity documentation,
it looks like it's both compatible and given an inspector walk through how to transcode it.

https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/Manual/VideoSources-FileCompatibility.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/Manual/VideoTransparency.html

however, as seen in the image below, the video is both not recognized as such and the inspector attributes are not as shown in the documentation
Do you know of an alpha supporting video format that is supported by Unity 2018.4LTS?

[image]
[image: how .mov looks in my inspector for all devices]

Comment: If you play the video into one plane you can change the alpha of that plane material.

Comment: @el6976 yes but if the video itself doesn't support transparency then the plane will at best only turn white or black at according pixels.. OP doesn't want the entire video to be transparent but rather support the alpha channel

Comment: Actually webm with VP8 should already support the alpha channel but only if this video was actually rendered with an alpha channel .. how do you generate the VP8 file?

Answer (score 1):

thank you all helpers,
WebM format with VP8 has indeed supported transparency and solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

Unity - make video background transparent - Mobile/PC

Check this link, It's working perfectly:  https://styly.cc/tips/tomo-chromakey/#

Credit to the author